# built interrelated data field validation flask WTF

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a booking form class defined as

```
class Booking(FlaskForm):
    room_type= HiddenField()
    check_in=DateField("Arrival Date",  [validators.Required("Select Arrival Date")], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    check_out=DateField("Departure Date",  [validators.Required("Select Departure Date")], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    adults = TextField("Adults",[validators.Required("No of Adults travelling are Mandatory!")])
    children = TextField("Children")
    name_booking = TextField("Name",[validators.Required("First Name is Mandatory!")])
    email_booking = EmailField("email ",[validators.Required("email is Mandatory!")])
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

I want to build a logic where check-in is always lesser than check-out.I tried

```
def chkdate(form, field):
    if field.data > check_in.data:
        raise ValidationError('Check Out cannot be before Check In')

class Booking(FlaskForm):
    room_type= HiddenField()
    check_in=DateField("Arrival Date",  [validators.Required("Select Arrival Date")], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    check_out=DateField("Departure Date",  [validators.Required("Select Departure Date"), chkdate()], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    adults = TextField("Adults",[validators.Required("No of Adults travelling are Mandatory!")])
```

based on [WTF Docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#custom-validators)

Comment: So what exactly is the question, does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

First the method name need to be of the form `validate_checkdate` and secondly the this need to be a method of `Booking` class and not a separate function.

So the updates code would look like below

```
class Booking(FlaskForm):
    room_type= HiddenField()
    check_in=DateField("Arrival Date",  [validators.Required("Select Arrival Date")], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    check_out=DateField("Departure Date",  [validators.Required("Select Departure Date"), chkdate()], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    adults = TextField("Adults",[validators.Required("No of Adults travelling are Mandatory!")])

    def validate_chkdate(form, field):
        if field.data > check_in.data:
            raise ValidationError('Check Out cannot be before Check In')
```

Comment: `validate_` is not important keyword as per docs. Correct? or you share exact reference.
Secondly, i am still getting this error > `check_out=DateField("Departure Date",  [validators.Required("Select Established Date"), validate_chkdate] , format='%Y-%m-%d')
NameError: name 'validate_chkdate' is not defined`

Lastly, `in-line validator` to do validation of a single field as per doc links